# Copying shapefiles within windows explorer (or - extension)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arccatalog

Is there a user-friendly way to copy shapefiles to a different file location?

ArcCatalog is not fast enough for this purpose, creating  new map and navigating to this new workspace takes a lot of time..

Does an extension for windows explorer (version 7) exist  (maybe specifying an advanced filter) ?

Comment: Could you please supply more details of what you hope to accomplish?  What purpose does creating a new map serve in moving shapfiles?  How would advanced filters help you?  As your question stands, I do not know why you would want to use Windows over ArcCatalog.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I use the Catalog window rather than ArcCatalog any time that I want to Copy manually and cannot see where you hope to save any steps by using Windows Explorer. Can you list your precise steps, please?

Comment: How does just copying the required files in Windows Explorer not work for you?

Comment: I work at a company thas has been reorganised: 3 settlements are working together now; so data has to be brought together. After this "move" I am thinking about copying the data to filegeodatabases (compact and indexed data). ArcPython is suitable for this second step.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would encourage you to use ArcCatalog as the GIS knows which files to move. People who try to move spatial data outside the GIS often miss important files/folders. I feel that integrity of the data is more important than the speed of copying.

Comment: For moving geodatabases and the (old) coverages I agree.

Comment: For moving geodatabases and the (old) coverages I agree. But with shapefiles there is no risk. I prefer an alternative program because ArcCatalog is rather slow because I have lots of shapes to move. I have been thinking using ArcPython for this job, but this is difficult to do: I want to make some subfolders depending on the theme in the shapefile (hydrology, recreation, agriculture, .). Creating those folders will probably be done interactively.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move Shapefiles across Windows systems, you could do this with RoboCopy.  I am not sure if you will see a huge gain in terms of processing time for completing the copy, but you might see 'some' improvement.  The challenge is knowing which files to copy for any of the Shapefiles you are concerned with, mainly since each Shapefile contains a combination of individual files which range across 15 different extensions.  Below is a link explaining those various file extensions which can participate as part of a Shapefile:

[File Extensions for a Shapefile](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005600000003000000)

To help speed things up (depending on the type of machines involved with the copy), when using RoboCopy you can try using the multi-threaded switch (e.g., /MT) if you are not using MS Server 2012 (the switch was removed at 2012).  Below is the user help for the RoboCopy command and its parameters:

[RoboCopy Command Help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx)

If you prefer not to use RoboCopy, you can still copy the individual files that make up the Shapefile(s) using a basic copy from Windows Explorer.

Comment: I'll have a look at Robocopy tomorrow. I should prefer one or other alternative program for explorer. I have a lot of shapefiles to copy; and I want to re-order them. So I need a program that can list the shapefiles (different submaps, but with ArcPy I have listed them to a text-file). At the rightsight I need the new destination drive+path. The program should be able to create several submaps at the same time and the selected files at the left should be copied (without interaction if possible).